# Set title of a button there is selected from an array - Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, button, title

I have a lot of buttons that i would like to give a title when the view is loaded.
The title of the buttons varies depending on what day of the month it is. Therefore I have created an array with the name of all the buttons. My code is as follows:

**My interface:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button6;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button7;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button8;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button9;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button10;
```

**My implementation:**

```
@synthesize button1 = _button1;
@synthesize button2 = _button2;
@synthesize button3 = _button3;
@synthesize button4 = _button4;
@synthesize button5 = _button5;
@synthesize button6 = _button6;
@synthesize button7 = _button7;
@synthesize button8 = _button8;
@synthesize button9 = _button9;
@synthesize button10 = _button10;

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"dummyButton", @"_button1", @"_button2", @"_button3", @"_button4", @"_button5", @"_button6", @"_button7", @"_button8", @"_button9", @"_button10", nil];

for (int i = varDefinedEarlier; i<=totalAmountOfNeededTitles; i++) {
     NSString *theTitleSting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
     NSLog(@"arrayValue:%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:i]); //Works prints the button name (for example _button7)


    [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:theTitleSting forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//The line above is where the app crashes. Everything else works just fine.
}
```

The error provided to me is a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Besides that, this is what the log says:

> -[__NSCFConstantString setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14a48
>   2012-07-10 22:57:49.649 Don't Break the Chain[10302:707] * * * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14a48'
>   * * * First throw call stack:
>   (0x3774788f 0x3544c259 0x3774aa9b 0x37749915 0x376a4650 0xdc2f 0x31454c8b 0x314611e9 0x31461059 0x31460f3f 0x3146070b 0x31460503 0x31454aff 0x314547d5 0x314cd903 0x31547627 0x37fb8933 0x3771ba33 0x3771b699 0x3771a26f 0x3769d4a5 0x3769d36d 0x33e5c439 0x31449cd5 0xb7cf 0xb774)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I think the error is the way i try to tell the app witch button it needs to set a title to, but I can not really figure out how to get it to take on the value of my array and use it as the button name.

I'm pretty new in iPhone iOS development, so bear with me if the answer is simple ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not referencing the button instances but some strings within that array. Now within your loop, you are trying to invoke the method setTitle:forState: on those strings which does not exist for NSString instances.

Try the following:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_button1, _button2, _button3, _button4, _button5, _button6, _button7, _button8, _button9, _button10, nil];
```

This will place the actual button instances into your array, as intended and your code should work fine.

Comment: Like i said.. Simple answer ;) Thank you very much for your help. It worked perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like `[myButton setTitle:[myArray objectAtIndex:i] forState: UIControlStateNormal]`

at the moment you are passing the setTitle message to a string type which - of course - should result in a crash...
hope it helps